# Space key is not working in Input field when Input field is placed inside Angular material tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I have an input field inside the angular material tab -

```
<mat-tab-group     headerPosition="below">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let sheet of sheets; let index = index">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>            
            <input type="text" (keydown)="onkeypress($event)">
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

All the key events are working fine, except space key. When I try to hit space key.

Note: If I press Ctrl+Space key, the space key works.

[image]

Comment: you might doing something inside onkeypress mehtod. please share onkeypress method code

Comment: @TheParam, I'm doing nothing. Just I did console.log() - 

onkeypress(event) { console.log(event); }
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use below code in your TS file

```
handleInput(event: KeyboardEvent): void{
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

And in your HTML file `(keydown)="handleInput($event)`
It'll work definately

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I missed a small thing.

Comment: @Kanchan. This really isn't a small thing. I still don't understand how this comes about. I understand the solution in so much as it doesn't let the event get any higher but why a space isn't added I'm still quite confused. I get this same issue even when adding a space in the middle of a word. Sometimes it works and sometimes not.